# How to split columns of the QtableWidget into subcolumns in Qt

Tags: qt

I am using QtableWidget for my GUI application.
In my GUI , I have to display a table widget which has Rows and Columns and for each row , column is further divided into two sub columns.

Can any body please tell me how to divide columns into subcolumn for Qtable Widget? (I need to divide horizontal header view also into sub columns).

Answer (score 1):

From the question it is unclear what/how you want to subdivide, but in general Qt has no concept of a subcolumn.

You can however control the display and editing of individual items using an item delegate. So I suggest you experiment with that.

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForRow